# Detecting SCL/SDA ports

Tags: gpio, i2c, mcu

I am working with the EFR32xG24 chips. There is a controller and multiple sensors with custom cables and connectors. For flexibility it would be desirable to connect the cable two ways, i.e. by rotating the connector and thus swapping some cables. Now lets say there are two GPIO Pins, C05 and C06 to which the two I2C cables are connected. I am wondering, whether it is possible to somehow detect if e.g. SCL is connected to C05 and SDA to C06 or if it is vice versa.

An approach would be to just route them one way and test wheter if works (potentially with some configuration communication) and if not, reset I2C and reroute the pins.

Another idea is as they are connected via GPIO, listen to one pin and detect, whether this one is the Clock or not.

Thanks for your Suggestions

Comment: While this is a programming question you may want to ask it on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: see [electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/690216/detecting-scl-sda-ports) if interested

Comment: Use GPIO bidirectional mux chips, there are plenty of those. Also there are I²C muxes in case devices are sharing the address.

Comment: The question has been answered over at the [electronics stackexchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/690216/detecting-scl-sda-ports).